# Let G be a group such that $(xy)^2 = (yx)^2$ for all x, y ∈ G. Show that $xy^2 = y^2x$ for all x, y ∈ G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm not quite sure if I did this right but I had another solution that made no sense to me:

This is the solution I do not understand. I did not solve it this way.

$=>(xy)^{-1}(xy)^2(yx)^{-1} = (xy)^{-1}(yx)^2(yx)^{-1}$

$=>(xy)(yx)^{-1} = (xy)^{-1}(yx)$

then somehow we have

$=> xy^2 = x((x^{-1}y)x)^2$

$=> xy^2 = x(x(yx^{-1}))^2$

$=> xy^2 = (xyx)^{-1}(xyx^{-1})x$

$=> xy^2 = y^2x$

I'm positive that the solution above is wrong I just need confirmation.

This is my solution:

Since G is a group then for all x,y ∈ G there exists $x^{-1}$ , $y^{-1}$ ∈ G.

$(xy)^2 = (yx)^2$

$y^{-1}x^{-1}xyxy = y^{-1}x^{-1}yxyx$

$xy = y^{-1}x^{-1}yxyx$

$y = x^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}yxyx$

Take the left hand side of $xy^2 = y^2x$ and substitute $y = x^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}yxyx$

$xy^2 = x(x^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}yxyx)^2$

$xy^2 = x(x^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}yxyx)(x^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}yxyx)$

$xy^2 = xx^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}yxyxx^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}yxyx$

$xy^2 = y^{-1}x^{-1}yyxyx$

$xy^2 = y^{-1}x^{-1}y^2xyx$

$xyxy^2 = y^2xyx$

$y^{-1}x^{-1}xyxy^2 = y^2xyxx^{-1}y^{-1}$

$xy^2 = y^2x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest proof I can come up with ( I can't tell whether yours is correct: too long for me, but it looks fine):

$$\color{red}{xyxy}\stackrel{Def.}=(xy)^2\stackrel{\text{given}}=(yx)^2\stackrel{Def.}=\color{blue}{yxyx}$$

Choose $\;y=x^{-1}y\;$ in the above:

$$\color{red}{xx^{-1}yxx^{-1}y}=\color{blue}{x^{-1}yxx^{-1}yx}\implies y^2=x^{-1}y^2x\implies xy^2=y^2x$$

Comment: Special cases... it's all about special cases :)

Comment: I just realized I could get $y = x^{-1}y$ without all the hassle. But I think my solution is correct.

Comment: I just found an error in my second last line. I think I will have to take your solution but I still don't get how we can get $y=x^{-1}yx$ from the given condition

Comment: @Malush The given condition is true **for all elements** $\;x,y\in G\;$ , right? Well, I take two elements $\;x,y\;$ , but instead of working with them *directly* I choose to work with $\;x\,,\,\,x^{-1}y\;$ .

Comment: I understand but wouldn't it make more sense to pick an element such as $y = x^{-1}u$ instead and substitute in for y? Where u is an arbitrary element

Comment: @Malush Why? The elements $\;x,y\in G\;$ are completely arbitrary, but instead $\;y\;$ alone I take the element $\;x^{-1}y\;$ together with $\;x\;$ , ant these two, of course,  are *also* completely arbitrary...Whta does "sense" have to do here? If you can come up with another option that'll render a shorter, clearer proof I'll love to see it...

Comment: With $y = x^{-1}y$ you're implying that any arbitrary element $y$ in product with the inverse of any arbitrary element $x$ gives you $y$ back. This seems like a big assumption even though it is not defined in the question.

Comment: @Malush I think you're missing big time the point of all this, and I cannot be any clearer. Perhaps someone else can explain this. Last advice: post a new question asking about **this precise point** ...

Answer (score 0):

This might be same argument as in previous answer:
$$(x^{-1}\cdot yx)^2=(yx\cdot x^{-1})^2 \,\,\,\, \Rightarrow \,\,\,\, x^{-1}y^2x=y^2.$$